# In Visual Studio, can I modify forms from the .exe file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am a rookie at this which I'm sure this question will show. Someone sent me an .exe file for a Visual Basic application and asked me to update some code. I'm not sure how to do this. When I open Visual Studio, it wants to find the .sln file which I don't seem to have. Is there a way to create the .sln file from the .exe or do I need to ask for the .sln file?

Comment: You can if you use a dissassembler, but in your case you should just ask the person who gave you the `.exe` to also give you the source-code...

Comment: You need the source files, which includes, but is not limited to, the SLN file.

Comment: They should send you a link to the repository for that project. Everything else would be unprofessional.

Comment: As noted, you might find a de-compiler. However, if someone sent you the file and asked you to modify it? Beat the person over the head with a really large frying pan, and ask them to send you the full project. Dealing with such silly people is beyond irresponsible on their part asking you to do a task without sending you the correct files for that given project.

Comment: LOL, Thank you. That's what I thought. Now I just need to find a big enough frying pan. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the source file that contains the source code.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/535986d2-5fd7-43ea-91b7-10b1234bc0f9/editing-an-executable-file?forum=vseditor